# Concatenate three 16-bit integers in one 64-bit integer with C++

Tags: c++, performance, integer, bitwise

I am looking for an elegant alternative of the following code where `wordXX` contains always 16 bits:

```
uint64_t wordHi = 0xaa; // I would like u_int16_t over u_int64_t here
uint64_t wordMi = 0xbb; // because it represents the real data better
uint64_t wordLo = 0xcc;

uint64_t largeword = (wordHi << 32) + (wordMi << 16) + (wordLo << 0);
```

To me this (very simplified) code looks a bit dirty, because reader gets confused about the real size of the `wordXX` data.

I could store `wordHi` to `largeword` and then shift `largeword` and add `wordMi` and so on, but this would make the code worse and probably needs more CPU cycles.

Edit: changed `u_int64_t` to `uint64_t` in the example as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Please either post your real code or remove the "very simplified" disclaimer.

Comment: The performance concerns of a handful of bit operations are almost certainly going to be negligible. Even if this is inside the tightest loop you can imagine, I highly doubt that you would see much of a performance hit over that, and I strongly doubt you could find a more readable and efficient method of doing that.

Comment: @200_success with simplified I want to express that the 16-bit integers are of course not constant values. So `largeword = 0xaabbcc;` would not help me a lot.

Comment: @Dannnno to me it looks strange to convert all 16-bit values to 64-bit, just to be able to shift them later. OK I could store `wordMi` to 32-bit and `wordLo` to 16-bit. But that makes it not much better...

Comment: Why are you using `u_int64_t` instead of the standard `uint64_t`? Why aren't you using `u_int16_t` for the words?

Comment: @200_success Thank you for pointing me to this. I was not aware, that uint64_t is the standard. Where does u_int64_t come from?

Comment: Dunno. You tell me. =)

Comment: @200_success do you have a link, where uint64_t is defined as a standard? I could not find a source that suggests uint64_t over u_int64_t.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using uint16_t not a problem?

Your comment says you want to use `uint16_t`, so why don't you do that?  It would make the code look like this:

```
uint16_t wordHi = 0xaa;
uint16_t wordMi = 0xbb;
uint16_t wordLo = 0xcc;

uint64_t largeword = ((uint64_t) wordHi << 32) + ((uint64_t) wordMi << 16) + wordLo;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a struct and a union to do what you want.  Note that this implementation is verbose and can be combined into a single declaration.  Also depending on your system architecture, you may need to pack the struct or declare the members in a different order.

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t Low;
  uint16_t Mid;
  uint16_t Hi;
  uint16_t Spare;
} Word64_t;

typedef union
{
  uint64_t Int64Val;
  Word64_t WordVal;
} Splitter_t;

Splitter_t splitter;
splitter.WordVal.Low = 0xaa;
splitter.WordVal.Mid = 0xbb;
splitter.WordVal.Hi = 0xcc;

printf("%x", splitter.Int64Val);  //should print 0xaabbcc
```

Comment: I think you would run into endianness issues with this solution.

Comment: @JS1 That may be. It depends on the architecture, as I said.  I do this all the time in embdeded.

Comment: If you can check the endianness of your architecture in a #define, you could define the order of elements in the struct differently based on the value of the #define.